# Angular: dynamically listen for attribute´s value change of modal dialog and add/remove class to the element

Tags: angular, typescript, attributes, modal-dialog, z-index

I´ve been trying to find solution for the problem: I have two sibling div tags. In the second one, there is a button to display modal dialog with the dark overlay, however, in my example the first div is sitting on the top of this modal dialog. I understand the reason why (stacking concept) but I need to create some working solution without changing this structure.

The modal dialog has boolean attribute opened. Is there any way I can dynamically listen to this attribute´s value and with the help of ngClass change the z-index of the second sibling to the highest one on the page when the modal is opened and remove this ngClass whenever the modal is no longer opened on the screen?

Thank you very much for any help or suggestion.

```
<div style='z-index: 2'></div>
<div style='z-index: 1'>
    <button (click)="openModal()">Open modal</button>
    <div id="modal" style='z-index: 3'>Here is the modal content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, I did that, but how do I then remove this higher z-index class if I can close modal with these possibilities: click cancel, click save, click x button and click away from modal?

Answer (score 0):

If changing structure is an option, I would recommend @Drenai's approch in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72206732/angular-dynamically-listen-for-attribute%C2%B4s-value-change-of-modal-dialog-and-add#comment127576014_72206732). However, if changing structure is not an option, here's a solution involving CSS, with bits taken from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp).

First, as you mentioned, maintain a boolean variable in your controller that states whether the modal is opened or not. (Let's name it `isModalOpened`.)

```ts
export class MyComponent {
    public isModalOpened = false;
}
```

In your stylesheet, position `div#modal` fixed; stretched to the ends of the screen. `div#modal` will serve as the overlay of the modal content, while the modal will serve as the actual modal box.

```css
/* the modal (background) */
#modal {
    position: fixed;                     /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1;                          /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;                         /* Full width */
    height: 100%;                        /* Full height */
    overflow: auto;                      /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);        /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);   /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* modal box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* modal close button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

In your HTML, wrap the content of your modal within a `.modal-content` div, and use `isModalOpened` to conditionally render the modal only when the modal's state is opened.

```html
<div>In 1st div tag.</div>

<div>
    <!-- set modal state to "open" when clicked -->
    <button (click)="isModalOpened = true">Open modal</button>

    <!-- render modal content when state is "open" -->
    <div id="modal" *ngIf="isModalOpened">

        <div class="modal-content">
           <p>Here is the modal content</p>

           <!-- set modal state to "close" when clicked -->
           <button class="close" (click)="isModalOpened = false">&times;</button>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Notice that when the "Open modal" button is clicked, `isModalOpened` is set to `true`, while clicking the modal's close button sets `isModalOpened` to `false`. This way, the modal's open and close functionality should work, all while your z-index issue is solved by `fixed`ing the modal's `position`.

Comment: Thank you very much Christian for your suggestion, however I have multiple possibilities of closing the modal: cancel button, save button, x button - which is in the DOM shadow root and also clicking away from the modal. I am looking for a general solution that would cover all these possibilities.

Comment: Hi @Victoria. Not to sound dismissive. I could go on and detail how to cover all your requirements, but at that point you might be better off looking into well-tested third-party packages instead. Hope that helps! :)